# How to read OpenGL Vertex2d's from a file?

Tags: c++, opengl, drawing, vertex

I made a code wich gives me vertexes of a 2d polygon with a desired number of sides to a file. it looks like this (for 5 sides):

```
 -0.000000, -1.000000 
 0.951057, -0.309017 
 0.587785, 0.809017 
 -0.587785, 0.809017 
 -0.951057, -0.309017
```

now i need OpenGL to read this data and use it to draw a polygon
until now i used a list of glVertex2d(x.x, y.y); but i want the number of sides to be defined by the user at the beginning.

my code looks like this:

```
void Display()
{
    glClearColor( 0.587234043, 0.537254902, 0.5293117, 1.0 );

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );


    glColor3f( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );


    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );


    glVertex2d( 0, 0);
    glVertex2d( 0, 0);
    glVertex2d( 0, 0);
    glVertex2d( 0, 0);
    glVertex2d( 0, 0);
    glVertex2d( 0, 0);
    glVertex2d( 0, 0);

    glEnd();

    glFlush();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to write a for loop? ...

Comment: opengl doesn't have file-reading functions, it's only job is interfacing with graphics hardware.  look up fread.

Comment: What about push_back(vertex);

Comment: @vakken: `push_pack` is not part of OpenGL either. The name it suggests it's part of some container structure/class like `std::vector` or `std::list`.